# Stop app from refreshing when going into background. (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Currently in my WKWebView app, if I press the home button then go back to the app, it restarts my app. I've put a print statement in updateUiView, and it seems that as soon as it goes into the background in refreshes it. I think this is happening because of something called Background app refresh. But in 'Background modes', Background fetch is unticked. So, I guess my question is, how do I stop the app from refreshing when it switches to background?

Other apps don't have the same behavior so it must be possible.

FYI: I'm using SwiftUi App lifecycle.

[image]

Edit:

This is my updateUiView:

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    if (uiView.canGoBack) {
        uiView.goBack()
    }
    uiView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
    
    ....

    guard let urlStr = URL("https://www.example.com") else {
        return
    }
    uiView.load(URLRequest(url: urlStr))  
}
```

Comment: What are you doing in `updateUiView`? If you are reloading the page, could you move the reloading to `makeUIView`?

Comment: It isn't to do with background fetch - That is a specific background service that you need to write code to use.

Comment: @user1046037 In updateUiView I'm mostly just loading the url like so: `uiView.load(URLRequest(url: urlStr))`

Comment: Could you remove that `load(URLRequest(url:)` in `updateUIView`. Do it only in the `makeUIView` and see if that meets your needs

Comment: @user1046037 Thanks for your suggestion, I have moved the code to makeUIView, but It still does the same thing.

Comment: Not sure, better to comment out all the lines other than the ones absolutely necessary. Log a print statement to see if `makeUIView` is called again. If so the view is getting re-created so the problem might be as to why it is re-created

Comment: @user1046037 I moved all of the code (not just the part that loads the url) in updateUIView to makeUIView, and It works! Thankyou for all of your help!

Comment: Also if you post your comment as an answer I'll happily accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`makeUIView` is called to create the view.
`updateUIView` is called multiple times to update the view

So anything you want to do just once, do it in the `makeUIView`

Move the code from `updateUIView` to `makeUIView` and check if things work as expected.